# Why does my where statement return no results?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm using Excel VBA to pull in data from an Access database.  My "Select" and "From" statements work fine. When I add the "Where" statement, I get no results. Can you help?!

```vb
Dim SDATE As String
Dim EDATE As String
Dim SQLstring As String

SDATE = Application.InputBox("Beginning Date", "Date 1", Format(Date - 31, "MM-DD-YY"))
EDATE = Application.InputBox("Ending Date", "Date 2", Format(Date, "MM-DD-YY"))

SQLstring = "SELECT tblitemhistory.HistDate, tblstockitems.MasterPNo, tblstockitems.ItemDescription, tblitemhistory.HistType, tblitemhistory.HistText, tblitemhistory.HistQty " & _
            "FROM tblitemhistory INNER JOIN tblstockitems ON tblitemhistory.StockID = tblstockitems.ItemID" & _
            "where (((tblitemhistory.HistDate)  between #" & [SDATE] & "# AND #" & [EDATE] & "#"""

getSQLString = SQLstring
```

I'm hoping to pull records between two dates, input by the user. I get no errors when I run the code, but I get no results either.

Comment: Can you please add the result of `Debug.Print getSQLString` so we can see which date and which format the date actually is? • Also note that in `where (((tblitemhistory.HistDate)  between` you open 3 parenthesis but you only close one. So either your code is incomplete or invalid.

Comment: PEH that's probably it, along with the 3 double-quotes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets from [SDATE] and [EDATE].  This is SQL syntax, not VBA syntax.

You might consider revising your format to mm/dd/yyyy, regional interpretation of dates may be causing you headaches.

See this:

https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/575420-literal-datetimes-their-delimiters

**Edit **

I just realized you're not terminating all these parens:  `(((tblitemhistory.HistDate)`.  You don't need any of them.  Also, Having 3 quotes at the end adds a quote to the end of your query that you probably don't want, try `"where tblitemhistory.HistDate BETWEEN #" & SDATE & "# AND #" & EDATE & "#"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I get the same result when I run the code.

Comment: Does the query return anything if you replace `" & [SDATE] & "` and `" & [EDATE] & "` with hard-coded values in the `"MM-DD-YY"` format?

Comment: I'm wondering, also, why you've got this in there: `getSQLString = SQLstring`, it doesn't do anything.  A bit of a red herring.

Comment: Hard coding the dates returns no results either. Something has to be goofy with my "where" statement in general...... getSQLString = SQLstring.... higher up in my code, I'm calling "getSQLstring" which goes to my Function and ultimately the SQL statement.  It allows me to use the same bit of code for the connection(s) and formatting and I only need to worry about changing pieces of the Function for different applications.  I can post the entire code if you think it would help.

Comment: Updated, I didn't look closely at your query.  MS likes to add a bunch of parens when you're using a query builder and it can make it pretty confusing to look at.  I make a habit of eliminating them, just for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are in a region that runs dates as day first as opposed to month first. Hence, whatever date ranges are entered no data exists according to that section since you do not receive any errors.

Consequently, consider two adjustments:

1. Remove any formatting and have user enter date in whatever region they are in and adjust dates from their CPU's default.
2. Use parameterization with MS Access' [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao) as opposed to SQL concatenation in your VBA as shown below with a DAO connection.

```vb
Sub RunQuery()
    Dim SDATE As Date, EDATE As Date
    Dim SQLstring As String
    Dim conn As Object, db As Object, qdef As Object

    SDATE = Application.InputBox("Beginning Date", "Date 1", Date - 31)   ' REMOVE Format()
    EDATE = Application.InputBox("Ending Date", "Date 2", Date)           ' REMOVE Format()

    Set conn = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
    Set db = conn.OpenDatabase("C:\Path\To\Database.accdb")

    ' PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA) - CAN BE SAVED IN MS ACCESS AS QUERY OBJECT
    SQLstring = "PARAMETERS [Prm_SDATE] Date, [Prm_EDATE] Date;" & _
                "SELECT i.HistDate, s.MasterPNo, s.ItemDescription," & _
                "       i.HistType, i.HistText, i.HistQty " & _
                "FROM tblitemhistory i " & _
                "INNER JOIN tblstockitems s ON i.StockID = s.ItemID" & _
                "WHERE i.HistDate BETWEEN [Prm_SDATE] AND [Prm_EDATE];"

    ' BIND PARAMETERS
    Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", SQLstring)
    qdef![Prm_SDATE] = SDATE
    qdef![Prm_EDATE] = EDATE

    ' OPEN RECORDSET
    Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset

    ' DUMP OUTPUT TO EXCEL SHEET
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close: db.Close        
    Set qdef = Nothing: Set db = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow Parfait, you are above my pay grade!  :-) I don't quite understand. If I were to post my entire code, would you be willing to tweak it?

Comment: The idea is you tweak this for your final solution. Essentially, it queries an Access database binding data values to parameters and dumps results into worksheet. I have comments in code to help.